# What can i use for a no-op in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, syntax

What's a good no-op in T-SQL? I want to use it as a place-holder in boilerplate code snippets. For example, if I'm stubbing out a query/UDF and have something like this:

```
IF @parm = 1
    BEGIN
    END
IF @parm = 2
    BEGIN
    END
```

I'll get the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the word 'END'

What could I throw in between there that would silence the compiler i.e. be executable?

Comment: HOw about a print statement print @parm

Comment: @Jon Egerton: Indeed, but I'm glad I missed it because @Abe's/@HLGEM's suggestion wasn't included there. (I suppose somebody ought to merge these two questions, but I'm not that meta.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could throw a `print` in there:

```
IF @parm = 1
    BEGIN
    print 'need to implement 1'
    END
IF @parm = 2
    BEGIN
    print 'need to implement 2'
    END
```

Answer (score 31):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3234871/empty-statement-in-t-sql) you could declare  a dummy variable. It shouldn't appear anywhere at all (execution plans, printed output etc):

```
IF @parm = 1
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @dummy1 bit
    END
IF @parm = 2
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @dummy2 bit
    END
```

Alternatively, you can use a label too:

```
IF @parm = 1
    BEGIN
        noop1:
    END
IF @parm = 2
    BEGIN
        noop2:
    END
```

Comment: Declaring a label worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Labels were working for me until I added a label to a scalar function.
SQL 2019 was giving me a "Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state." error if that function was referenced in code somewhere. If I added a reference in the function "IF 1=2 GOTO Label" then it didn't fail.
I opted to use the Variable declaration.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try...

```
WAITFOR DELAY '0:0';
```